# Your content folder in "/home/{????}/public_html/wp-content/uploads" is not writeable

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, whm

I am getting the same error on my both WordPress sites:

Your content folder in "/home/{my_user}/public_html/wp-content/uploads" is not writeable.

They both are hosting on a dedicated service using WHM.

I changed the permission on the ../uploads/ folder to 777 and it works but I don't think this is a valid exercise.
The current setting on the folder is 775

Can you please give me some steps to diagnose this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange enough, the issue was that our LiteSpeed license was expired and the webserver was switched to Apache and it was missing the proper user configuration.

Everything fixed when we fixed the license issue with LiteSpeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#changing-file-permissions)  on how to set the correct permissions / hardening your wordpress installation, which states:

> If you have shell access to your server, you can change file permissions recursively with the following command: 
>
> **For Directories:** 
> `find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` 
>
> **For Files:** 
> `find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

There's also [a similar stackoverflow question which goes into a little bit more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress).